# Load another HTML page to create an JavaScript array using .get and .each

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

So I've banged my head on this all day. I'm updating the code.

I'm trying to pull an array based off of an HTML page (we'll call this switcher1.html) where there is a list.

Based on this array, the javascript will randomly load one item of the array onto the page where the javascript is called (we'll call this index.html).

//

```
// Random Profile

//


function randomProfile() {
var profilePages = [];



$.get( "/js/switcher1.html #featured-faculty", function() { 
    $("ul li").each(function( index ) { 
        profilePages.push($(this).text()) 
        });


    });

var randomPage = Math.floor(Math.random() * profilePages.length);
$('#featured-profile').load(profilePages[randomPage]);


}

// Run these functions as soon as this script is loaded,
// instead of waiting for the DOM to finish loading
randomProfile();
```

Hopefully you can see that the goal is to pull in a list from another source so I won't have to type it in to the JavaScript doc manually. My array is turning up blank no matter what I try.

FYI - I can use JQuery but not other code libraries. Also, I'm doing it this way due to a (slightly annoying & convoluted) CMS. The CMS can output an HTML list, so this is the best solution I was able to come up with.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Too many unknown variables for anyone to answer this.  Can you use Firebug to check for any errors, check whether "profilePages" is getting populated, etc?

Comment: The first parameter of `jQuery.get()` is a URL. You can't add a selector as well. You'll have to parse the result of the ajax call after you get the page.

Comment: @McGarnagle - That is the problem, the profilePages is not getting populated. Let me know what other info is needed and I'll fill it in.